# How to program the strategy to ignore certain signals?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image]

```
//@version=5
strategy("My script")

uptrend = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", (ta.ema(close, 9) > ta.ema(close, 21)))
downtrend = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", (ta.ema(close, 9) < ta.ema(close, 21)))

buy = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", ta.crossover(ta.ema(close, 9), ta.ema(close, 21)))
sell = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", ta.crossunder(ta.ema(close, 9), ta.ema(close, 21)))

if uptrend
    if buy
        strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)

if sell
    strategy.close("buy")

if downtrend
    if sell
        strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short)

if buy
    strategy.close("sell")
```

how do i implement the script to ignore the rest of the signals after the first signal has occured as shown in the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
strategy("My script")

var tradeplaced = 0
uptrend = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", (ta.ema(close, 9) > ta.ema(close, 21)))
downtrend = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", (ta.ema(close, 9) < ta.ema(close, 21)))

buy = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", ta.crossover(ta.ema(close, 9), ta.ema(close, 21)))
sell = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", ta.crossunder(ta.ema(close, 9), ta.ema(close, 21)))

if uptrend and uptrend[1]==false
    tradeplaced:=0
if downtrend and downtrend[1]==false
    tradeplaced:=0

if uptrend
    if buy and tradeplaced==0
        strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)
        tradeplaced:=1
if sell
    strategy.close("buy")

if downtrend
    if sell and tradeplaced==0
        strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short)
        tradeplaced:=1
if buy
    strategy.close("sell")
```

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]